# GitLab CI runner with Docker executor fails to clone repository

Tags: git, docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I would like to use GitLab CI on my institution's GitLab instance to run unit tests for my Python project.

I have written a simple job in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
test-job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something"
```

I had defined a first runner with Shell executor on my machine.

When pushing new commits on the GitLab instance repo, the job ran successfully with this first runner.

I also successfully ran the job locally with: `sudo gitlab-runner exec shell test-job`

I then defined a second runner with Docker executor (and paused the first runner on the GitLab instance).
I also added `image: continuumio/miniconda3` right before `stage: test` in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

When pushing to the remote repo, the job fails with this second runner, and returns the following error:

```
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password. See http://gitlab2.xxx.xx/help/topics/git/troubleshooting_git#error-on-git-fetch-http-basic-access-denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://gitlab2.xxx.xx/xxx/xxx.git/'
```

I successfully ran the job locally with: `sudo gitlab-runner exec docker test-job`

What am I doing wrong to run this test using Docker executor when pushing to the GitLab instance?

Should I add variables to store credentials and access the GitLab instance? In that case how did the Shell runner succeed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `clone_url` parameter for the runner with docker executor in my gitlab-runner config file on my machine (`/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`) fixed my issue (based on this GitLab CI/CD [forum post](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/url-returns-500-when-running-job/28416)).